# Why didn't Prof Lupin allow Harry Potter to cast a spell on the Dementor?

Tags: harry-potter

Prof Lupin didn't allow Harry Potter to cast a spell on the Dementor during the Boggart class in *Harry Potter and the Prisoner of Azkaban*:

[image: The Boggart as a Dementor lunges for Harry but Lupin stands in front of him blocking its path]

Is there any reason?

Comment: Did you continue watching the film? Professor Lupin explains why a little bit later on when Harry asks him this exact question.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I believe this is a mistake on the film's part. In the books Lupin stops the Boggart before it can transform before Harry.

> ‘Riddikulus!’ bellowed Ron, and the spider’s legs vanished. It rolled over and
> over; Lavender Brown squealed and ran out of its way and it came to a halt at Harry’s feet. He raised his wand, ready, but –
>
> ‘Here!’ shouted Professor Lupin suddenly, hurrying forward.
>
> Crack!
>
> The legless spider had vanished. For a second, everyone looked wildly around
> to see where it was. Then they saw a silvery white orb hanging in the air in front
> of Lupin, who said ‘Riddikulus!’ almost lazily.
>
> <sub>*Harry Potter and the Prisoner of Azkaban*, Chapter 7, "The Boggart in the Wardrobe"</sub>

The same reasoning is given from Lupin for both the book and the film: he didn't want Voldemort showing up in class and frightening everyone.

> ‘No,’ Harry lied. He drank a bit of tea and watched the Grindylow brandishing a
> fist at him. ‘Yes,’ he said suddenly, putting his tea down on Lupin’s desk. ‘You
> know that day we fought the Boggart?’
>
> ‘Yes,’ said Lupin slowly.
>
> ‘Why didn’t you let me fight it?’ said Harry abruptly.
>
> Lupin raised his eyebrows.
>
> ‘I would have thought that was obvious, Harry,’ he said, sounding surprised.
> Harry, who had expected Lupin to deny that he’d done any such thing, was
> taken aback.
>
> ‘Why?’ he said again.
>
> ‘Well,’ said Lupin, frowning slightly, ‘I assumed that if the Boggart faced you, it
> would assume the shape of Lord Voldemort.’
>
> Harry stared. Not only was this the last answer he’d expected, but Lupin had
> said Voldemort’s name. The only person Harry had ever heard say the name
> aloud (apart from himself) was Professor Dumbledore.
>
> ‘Clearly, I was wrong,’ said Lupin, still frowning at Harry. ‘But I didn’t think it a good idea for Lord Voldemort to materialise in the staff room. I imagined that
> people would panic.’
>
> ‘I did think of Voldemort first,’ said Harry honestly. ‘But then I – I remembered
> those Dementors.’
>
> ‘I see,’ said Lupin thoughtfully. ‘Well, well … I’m impressed.’ He smiled slightly
> at the look of surprise on Harry’s face. ‘That suggests that what you fear most of
> all is – fear. Very wise, Harry.
>
> <sub>*Harry Potter and the Prisoner of Azkaban*, Chapter 8, "Flight of the Fat Lady"</sub>

> **Harry:** Professor, can I ask you something?
>
> **Lupin:** You want to know why I stopped you facing that boggart, yes? I would've thought it'd be obvious. I assumed it would take the shape of Lord Voldemort.
>
> **Harry:** I did think of Voldemort at first. But then I remembered that night on the train... and the dementor.
>
> **Lupin:** I'm very impressed. That suggests what you fear the most is fear itself. This is very wise.
>
> <sub>*Harry Potter and the Prisoner of Azkaban*</sub>

The change appears to have been made to make Harry's greatest fear, the Dementors/fear itself, more obvious for the audience at the expense of having the initial scene make a little less sense. One could argue that Lupin was going to stop the Boggart before he saw it was a Dementor when he saw Harry was next, he does look concerned. However, the filming of the scene doesn't really make this clear.